# Can micro black hole hold electron and create atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, black-holes, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, orbitals

Protons have a positive charge and hold negatively charged electrons in atoms. Thanks, quantum mechanics rules electrons don't fall to the nucleus. If we substitute the atomic nucleus with a micro black hole about radius 10^-15 meters whether electron will fall to the event horizon or will keep on any high above the event horizon by Heisenberg-uncertainty-principle? How will electrons behave according to general relativity and quantum mechanics if the black hole radius/mass increases or decreases?

Comment: The electron in a hydrogen atom has a lot of wave function at the nucleus. In the case of a black hole, well, bye bye electron.

Comment: BTW, a 1e-15 m Schwarzschild BH (which has a mass of 6.73326E11 kg) has a Hawking radiation temperature ~1.82223E11 K. See https://www.vttoth.com/CMS/physics-notes/311-hawking-radiation-calculator That's not exactly a friendly environment for a bound electron. ;)

Answer (score 3):

A normal micro-black hole has a high Hawking temperature and will evaporate quickly. However, if it is extremal (that is, rotating fast enough or charged enough) the Hawking temperature is zero. Hence [it has been proposed by F.C. Adams that Planck mass black extremal holes could remain stable](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0006062), and since they cannot change charge without accreting particles (that would have a hard time tunnelling into their tiny event horizons) they could form "atoms"  with captured electrons (or positrons) with a lifetime of $10^{49}$ years (they could also form "atoms" with orbiting protons, with lifetimes of $10^{37}$). No such atoms have been observed, so far.

The behaviour of electrons around black holes would be described by solving the Schrödinger or [Dirac equation in the Schwarzschild (or Kerr-Newman) metric](https://www.ias.ac.in/public/Volumes/pram/008/06/0500-0511.pdf). My impression of the results is that for small holes they behave much like in a hydrogen atom, but with slight shifts of the energy levels.